# Silverlight toolkit for windows phone 7 error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

Before I start with my problem, i would just like to say I am very new to programming, so I would really appreciate it if your answers are specific.

I added the Silverlight Toolkit (Nov 2011) to my Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. I already add the `.dll` to the reference.

I used the TimePicker tool in my application. However when i run it, i get an error:

`"Invalid attribute value controls:LongListSelector for property TargetType. [Line: 440 Position: 12]"`

After searching online about this problem, most of the answers given was to add this to the xaml:

`xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"`

That line was already in my xaml, but at the end it only said `"...Microsoft.Phone.Controls"`. So i just added the `.Toolkit"`

But the error still remains. The following line was highlighted in the `MainPage.g.i.cs`:
`System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/WindowsPhoneApplication1;component/MainPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));`

---

By the way, i just realized that there was already another prefix with the same code i.e. `xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"`

So now i have changed the 'controls' prefix to the way it was i.e. `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"`

The error is still there though.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="WindowsPhoneApplication1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" 
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" 
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Content="Refresh" Height="71" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="309,60,0,0" Name="buttonRefresh" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Click="button1_Click" />
        <TextBlock Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,28,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Current time:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBlock Height="47" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,70,0,0" Name="textBlockCurrentTime" Text="Press Refresh to view" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="251" FontSize="25" DataContext="{Binding}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Foreground="#FF05BFFF" Opacity="1" IsHitTestVisible="True" />
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,276,0,251" Name="textBoxHour" Text="0" Width="101" FontSize="20">
            <TextBox.InputScope>
                <InputScope>
                    <InputScopeName NameValue="TelephoneNumber" /> 
                </InputScope>
            </TextBox.InputScope>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="174,276,0,0" Name="textBoxMin" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" FontSize="20">
            <TextBox.InputScope>
                <InputScope>
                    <InputScopeName NameValue="TelephoneNumber" />
                </InputScope>
            </TextBox.InputScope>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,276,70,0" Name="textBoxSec" Text="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" FontSize="20">
            <TextBox.InputScope>
                <InputScope>
                    <InputScopeName NameValue="TelephoneNumber" />
                </InputScope>
            </TextBox.InputScope>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="63,349,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Hours" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91" />
        <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,349,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Min" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91" />
        <TextBlock Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,349,70,0" Name="textBlock4" Text="Sec" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="91" />
        <TextBlock Height="109" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,460,0,0" Name="textBlockResult" Text="Press Add" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" FontSize="30" />
        <Button Content="Add" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,381,0,0" Name="buttonAdd" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="buttonAdd_Click" />
        <toolkit:TimePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,197,0,0" Name="timePickerCustomTime" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="73" Width="273" IsEnabled="False" />
        <CheckBox Content="Use custom time" Height="73" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,123,0,0" Name="checkBoxCustomTime" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

---

Comment: You have no LongListSelector in the XAML you've posted. What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

As seen your error, you have not referenced correctly Toolkit.

Then, if I can help you with a little advice. You should install Nuget to easily manage your packages.

[Nuget](http://nuget.codeplex.com/)